# How can I pull data from an API and save it on a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to pull some data from a Zendesk API and I'm using UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options) function. Then I am trying to save the entire data into a google sheets but basically the same data is being saved in all cells of the spreadsheet.

What should I do to ensure that I store all data from the API call into a spreadsheet populating the cells correctly? (splitting the data into columns and rows)

Thank you!

Code I'm using:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options)
var fact = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.getRange("A1:WW5000").setValues([fact]);
```

What I am getting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNLbd.png)

Comment: Please share `response.getContentText()` and also provide us with a [mcve] and - [Welcome to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

You need to first get the exact data that you want to populate in Sheets. In your existing code, you are trying to populate the response object directly in Sheets. We cannot populate an object in Sheets. I assume there must be a field within the response object which would have data that you want to populate.

Try modifying the code to something like below :-

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options)
var fact = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
console.log('fact: '+JSON.stringify(fact));
   
var skips = fact.skips;
var values = [];
for(var i=0; i<skips.length; i++) {
  values.push([skips[i].id, skips[i].ticket_id, skips[i].user_id, ...]);
}

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
// Make sure to double check / modify this range to fit no. of rows and fields in skips. Or make it dynamic.
sheet.getRange("A1:WW5000").setValues(values);
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you are still stuck.

Comment: Thank you!!!
ok my output is something like this:
{"skips":[{"id":12345,"ticket_id":12345,"user_id":12345,"reason":null,"created_at":"2022-08-25T12:03:45Z","updated_at":"2022-08-25T12:03:45Z","ticket":{"url":"https://company.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/1234.json","id":1234,
And it goes on and on... I can't even understand where each entry ends :/ 

I have tried this code below:

    var values = fact.skips;
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.getRange("A1:WW5000").setValue(values);

But it's still pasting the same data in the cells, duplicating the data. :(

Comment: I've updated the answer based on your response now. Please check.

Comment: Hi there! Thank you! Now the code is not adding anything to the spreadsheet :(
I added this to the code : console.log(values.lenght); to try to understand the lenght but in the console I get "undefined" not sure if the spreadsheet being blank is related to this :/

Comment: Typo in lenght - It should be console.log(values.length). Try logging at each step to debug or please share sample sheet for me to check.

Comment: To ensure we can address your queries more effectively, may be you can reach out directly via email mentioned in profile https://stackoverflow.com/users/11197483/ab-it-gcp?tab=profile if it's easier for you. This way, we can avoid some back and forth and resolve it. The answer can be updated here accordingly.

Comment: Copy that! I will send the issue via email. Thank you!

Comment: I didn't receive it yet. Make sure there wasn't any typo in emailid.